# How to remove languages (that are not in the list of the "preferred languages") in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, system-preferences

The list of the "preferred languages" (*Settings -> Time & Language -> Language -> Proferred Languages*) contains only three entries. At the same time the list of available languages, I can switch between, contains two additional ones.

[image: Windows-10-Settings-Preferred-languages]

[image: Windows-10-Settings-language-switch]

**How to make the (two in this case: *German Switzerland* and *Spanish Spain*) entires be disaplyed in the language settigs? How to remove some of them (in this case: *German Switzerland*)?**